# Apache not recognizing directories other than root

Tags: apache, ubuntu, laravel

When trying to load anything other than www.example.com (for example, www.example.com/something), I get an error from apache indicating that 'the requested URL /something was not found on this server'.

Any ideas on what the issue may be? 
I'm running a laravel app on Digital Ocean - LAMP/Ubuntu.

My apache2.conf file (stripped of comments):

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300


KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf


<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /var/www/html/scheduleify/app/public
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>


AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent



IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf


Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

EDIT: Also the sites-enabled conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/scheduleify/public

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: What does sites-enabled look like.

Comment: Added the conf file contents above - hope this helps somehow

Comment: So DocumentRoot is /var/www/html/scheduleify/public ... do you have something.html in that directory?

Comment: that was my next question, and what do you get at www.example.com

Comment: I have my laravel apps index.php file there, as well as assets for the app.

Comment: When I go to www.example.com, I get the view that belongs in the '/' route... But none of my other views seem to work.

Comment: Looks like Apache is working, but may be a Larvel config issue?? I am not a Laravel guy so I really can't help with how it works with Apache. You might edit your question and add these details and more if you can regarding how it is laid out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is a web server -- its main job is to serve files to the web.  If it's telling you there's no file at

```
http://example.com/foo/baz/bar
```

then there's no file there.  It's working as it should

Laravel is a PHP application that works by running the file `index.php`.  If

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/index.php
```

is rendering correctly via Laravel, that means Laravel is working.

In order to make URLs like

```
http://example.com/foo/baz/bar
```

render via Laravel, Laravel includes a `.htaccess` file in the `public` folder that redirects **most if not all all** URLs to `index.php`.  It's this `.htaccess` file that's responsible for turning

```
http://example.com/foo/baz/bar
```

into

```
http://example.com/index.php/foo/baz/bar
```

In a working system this happens behind the scenes.  i.e. from a user looking at their browser point of view, the URL remains `http://example.com/foo/baz/bar`

If URLs in the second form are rendering on your server, then it's almost certainly an `.htaccess` issue.  In whichever `<Directory` node you're configuring your webroot, you want something like this

```
AllowOverride All
```

This tells Apache "hey, let the user use a `.htaccess` file to reconfigure everything you can configure from an `.htaccess` file.  You can find more information [about AllowOverride on the apache docs site](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html).

Comment: I figured this out on accident - but you are correct. The AllowOverride was incorrectly set. Thanks for the thorough explanation!